# angular 2 primeng multiselect required

Tags: angular

I want to use [PRIMENG multiselect](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect) instead of select in html. Everything works fine, but i want to make it required for some reason. I cannot do it same way like in select. How to make it [required]="!this.isAdmin":

```
  <!--<select multiple class="form-control" id="authorities" [required]="!isAdmin" [(ngModel)]="user.authorities" name="authorities" #tempAuthorities="ngModel">
    <option *ngFor="let auth of authorities" [value]="auth.auth" >{{ auth.title }}</option>
  </select>-->
  <p-multiSelect id="authorities" class="form-control" name="authorities" [options]="clients" [(ngModel)]="user.authorities"  #tempAuthorities="ngModel"></p-multiSelect>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's too late or not but here is my workaround to solve it.

you can just add another select list for your validation here is the steps

1. Add a normal select List and make it 'multiple' and 'required'
2. make it take the same model as the p-multiSelect
3. make it hidden

```html
  <p-multiSelect id="authorities" class="form-control" name="authorities" [options]="clients" [(ngModel)]="user.authorities"  #tempAuthorities="ngModel"></p-multiSelect>

<select name="reflection" [hidden]="true" multiple required [(ngModel)]="user.authorities"></select>
```